# Not all results are showing up in query with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

This is my query:

```
SELECT gang. * , players.Gang, COUNT( players.Gang ) AS total_members, SUM( players.Cash + players.Bank ) AS total_wealth
FROM gang
INNER JOIN players
WHERE players.Gang-1 = gang.gangID
AND gang.gangName != 'none'
GROUP BY gang.gangID
ORDER BY total_wealth DESC
```

Only shows 3 results instead of 5.

Trying to get:

```
Gang 1 | Total Wealth: $200,000 | Members: 8
Gang 2 | Total Wealth: $100,000 | Members: 5
Gang 3 | Total Wealth: $90,000  | Members: 3
Gang 4 | Total Wealth: $80,000  | Members: 2
Gang 5 | Total Wealth: $90,000  | Members: 1
```

Comment: please post some data with tables in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Where is your `ON` join condition?